# Why do we prove that $x_1$ = $x_2$ when looking if a function is injective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions

For a function to be considered injective, we consider that $\forall x_1, x_2 \in X, x_1 \neq x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$.

Now, when it comes to proving this, we prove that $\forall x_1, x_2 \in X, x_1 = x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, and if it turns out that $x_1 = x_2$, that means that the function is injective, but injectivity means that every $x$ has maps to only one, unique $y$, and we proved that it is not. (?)

So, why do we try to prove the opposite, and if it proves correct we consider it injective?

Comment: No, you prove that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$. The converse always hold for every function.

Comment: You are using mathjax wrong. You should write `$\forall x \in X$`  instead of `$\forall$ $x$ $\in$ $X$`.

Comment: @Surb can you elaborate on that one?

Comment: @jjagmath thank you for the edit, didn't know.

Comment: I think that your problem come from the fact that you don't think well injectivity. When you say : *injectivity means that every $x$ map to only one value.* That's wrong. This is more the definition of a function. Injectivity would rather be : $f:X\to Y$ is injective if for all $y\in Y$, there is at most one $x\in X$ s.t. $y=f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove $1-1$, you are right that we consider that $\forall x_1, x_2 \in X, x_1 \neq x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$ 
For the other part, just take contrapositive of above statement to get: 
$\forall x_1, x_2 \in X,   f(x_1) = f(x_2)\Rightarrow x_1=x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

To prove "Any two different inputs give two different outputs" it is enough to prove the equivalent statement: "if two inputs give the same output, then actually they are the same input".